# Как выдать определенные права роли в дискорде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Возникла проблема: *Пытаюсь настроить роль мута, но надо, чтобы у нее не было прав отправки сообщений.* Как это возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте **discord.Permissions**:

```py
permissions = discord.Permissions(read_messages=False)
```

Чтобы выдать эти права роли, сделайте вот так:

```py
role = guild.create_role(name='имя роли', permissions=permissions)
```

Comment: Спасибо **большое**!

Comment: Не за что))))..